# Can I create Submit button with observeEvent in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

i just stuck in observeEvent when i want to create submit button , the event doesn't make any action when i got to clicked, for the example here my code for the modal:

```
column(width = 6,
bs4Card(width = 12, collapsible = FALSE, title = "Follow Up",
selectInput("cara_fu", "Cara Follow up", 
choices = c('Call','Whatsapp', 'Visit')),
selectInput("hasil_fu", "Hasil Follow up",
choices = c('Survey', 'Batal', 'Unreachable')),
textAreaInput("ket_fu", "Keterangan",height = '100px'),
footer = actionButton("submit_fu", "Submit", status = "success")
 )
)
```

then when the form has been input by the value, the observeEvent will be generate by this code :

```
    # IF USER CLICKS SUBMIT FOLLOWUP, SAVE THE DATA IN DATABASE
  observeEvent(input$submit_fu, {
        text = tagList(
        selectInput("cara_fu", "Cara Follow up", 
        choices = c('Call','Whatsapp', 'Visit'), selected = df$cara_fu),
        selectInput("hasil_fu", "Hasil Follow up", 
        choices = c('Survey','Batal', 'Unreachable'), selected = df$hasil_fu),
        textInput("ket_fu", "Keterangan")
               )
  }) # End observe submit button
```

and when this button cliked nothing happen , im glad when all of u can find whats wrong here thanks

and here for the full code :

```
shiny::observeEvent(input$current_id, {
shiny::req(!is.null(input$current_id) &
             stringr::str_detect(input$current_id,
                                 pattern = "followup"
             ))
rv$dt_row <- which(stringr::str_detect(rv$df$Buttons,
                                       pattern = paste0("\\b", input$current_id, "\\b")
))
showModal(
  modalDialog(title = "Followup", easyClose = TRUE, size = "l",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 6,
                         bs4Card(width = 12, collapsible = FALSE, title = "Profile Summary",
                                 boxProfile(
                                   image = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg",
                                   title = (rv$df$nama_customer[rv$dt_row]),
                                   subtitle =(rv$df$no_hp_customer[rv$dt_row]),
                                   bordered = TRUE,
                                   boxProfileItem(
                                     title = "Jadwal Followup",
                                     description =rv$df$scheduled_followup[rv$dt_row]),
                                   boxProfileItem(
                                     title = "Produk",
                                     description = rv$df$produk[rv$dt_row]),
                                   boxProfileItem(
                                     title = "Status",
                                     description = rv$df$status[rv$dt_row])
                                 )
                         ),
                         bs4Card(width = 12, collapsible = FALSE, title = "History Followup",
                                 timelineBlock(
                                   width = 12,
                                   timelineLabel(as.Date(Sys.Date()), color = "primary"),
                                   timelineItem(
                                     title = "Followup 1",
                                     icon = icon("book"),
                                     color = "secondary",
                                     time = "now",
                                     "This is the body"
                                     ),
                                   
                                   timelineLabel(as.Date(Sys.Date()), color = "primary"),
                                   timelineItem(
                                     title = "Followup 3",
                                     icon = icon("book"),
                                     color = "secondary"
                                     )
                                   )
                                 )
                         ),
                  column(width = 6,
                         bs4Card(width = 12, collapsible = FALSE, title = "Follow Up",
                                 selectInput("cara_fu", "Cara Follow up", 
                                             choices = c('Call','Whatsapp', 'Visit')),
                                 selectInput("hasil_fu", "Hasil Follow up",
                                             choices = c('Survey', 'Batal', 'Unreachable')),
                                 textAreaInput("ket_fu", "Keterangan",height = '100px'),
                                 footer = actionButton("submit_fu", "Submit", status = "success")
                                 )
                         )
                )
              ),
              footer = tagList(
                modalButton("Cancel"),
                actionButton("ok", "OK")
                )
              )
  )
 observeEvent(input$submit_fu, {
               text = tagList(
                 selectInput("cara_fu", "Cara Follow up", 
                             choices = c('Call','Whatsapp', 'Visit'), selected = df$cara_fu),
                 selectInput("hasil_fu", "Hasil Follow up", 
                             choices = c('Survey','Batal', 'Unreachable'), selected = df$hasil_fu),
                 textInput("ket_fu", "Keterangan")
               )
      }) # End observe submit button 
  }) # End observe followup button
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: i will, wait a minute

Comment: To run the application (`shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`) there is no `ui` or `server` function in your edited code.

Comment: i was write full code, the proggram is running but not with the submit button, when i click there's nothing happen

Comment: The program is not running for me after copying your code.

Comment: oh wait i will copy all my code

Comment: Reducing your code to a minimal reproducible example might help people to help you (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).